# Django manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api

My django Application with Gmail_Api is not working properly which causes the error in starting the server

I Googled and tried this ..
[manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver 8000, Google Analytics API Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551454/manage-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-runserver-8000-google-analytics-api-d/46553099#46553099)
but still it is not working

```py
def Gmail_Call():
   try:
        import argparse
        flags = tools.argparser.parse_args([])
   except ImportError:
        flags = None
   SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
   CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
   APPLICATION_NAME = 'reportingtool'
   authInst = auth.auth(SCOPES,CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,APPLICATION_NAME)
   credentials = authInst.get_credentials()
   http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
   service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
   from . import Gmail_Msg_Function as from_google
   sendInst = from_google.send_email(service)
   msg = sendInst.create_message(sender='frommail_ID@gmail.com',to='tomail_ID@gmail.com',subject='test mail',message_text='testmsg')

   sendInst.send_message(user_id='me',message=msg)
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\www\Desktop\New\Project>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

usage: manage.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                 [--noauth_local_webserver]
                 [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                 [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a virtualenv or django installed in your local machine?